# Can I download android studio with this computer?

Tags: android, android-studio

Installed Ram : 8.00 GB (7.70 GB Usable)
System type: 64 bit operating system

I tried to download it but the emulator is not working and it doesnt show

Comment: please enable virtucal device from boot

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Android Studio would run perfectly on your machine, provided all the resources are utilized running the Android Studio.

For the emulator, you can either use an Android phone and test your apps on that, or you can use some light-weight emulators.